# how to change the code of other modules in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example.I installed a module in the node_modules. if i change that module, updating node_module will update all modules.What is the usual practice

Comment: Use patch-package https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Answer (score 3):

### Look into [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package)

In summary, you install the package and add a `postinstall` script to your package.json file that calls patch-package:

```json
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "patch-package"
 }
```

Modify the package directly in `/node_modules` and then call `patch-package` on the package you just modified:

```sh
npx patch-package <package_name>
```

This will create a local directory called `/patches` with a diff (or patch) file inside for that package. Commit that folder in with your repo.

Now whenever you run `npm install`, the `postinstall` script will also run and apply the `/patches` that you committed to that package

Comment: Another situation is. I use webpack to bundle packages. but those packages are usually distributed. if so. Do I only have to fork that repository to make changes?

Answer (score 0):

First, We call it `Package` instead of `Module`, Why? because search results on Google are much more accurate when you use that word

Second, to update a specific package use `npm update {package name}`

Third, you don't change the code of other packages, you can only either `install`, `update`, or `delete` the package. there's this option to override it but it's only possible if the package owner allows overrides.

## Update

I decided to update my answer due to the discussion below.

since I have put in mind that you are a beginner and are not entirely sure how to update code or override package code, or maybe even if it's a good idea to change package code, I have given you an unclear answer.

and since the other answer are telling you to use `patch-package`
then I'm here to tell you that you can fork that package. and install that package from your fork. [here's how you do it](https://blaipratdesaba.com/how-to-use-an-npm-node-module-that-has-been-forked-b7dd522fdd08)

Comment: Not correct, there are cases where the update is pending  and you may want an urgent fix. In such scenario patch-package can be used.

Comment: I wonder if that's usual practice.. the way I would modify packages is to fork the package.. update the code.. then use that fork to install the package..

benefits would be an easy update, easy modification, and easy replacement.
no need to have a local copy in my project.

Comment: It is not realistic to create a fork for each and every changes. It is a tedious process sometimes when all you want is a minor fix or change. This is for the exact purpose library like patch-package came into existence. Take for example this issue here in github https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279 a lot of us used patch-package to quickly solve the isssue until the fix is available.

Comment: well then if you really want that to be the "USUAL PRACTICE" then maybe at least let them know the consequences of their actions.

https://github.com/ds300/patch-package#when-to-fork-instead
https://github.com/ds300/patch-package#isnt-this-dangerous

Comment: It is not about "USUAL PRACTICE". It really depends on what the use case is. We cannot put everything under single bracket and say, it must be fork only or patch only. I am sure we all have different use cases. If it works without any issue for them, then why not.